# refactor es5 to es6 to avoid declaring temporary variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a codebase where tempVar are everywhere, just like below example

```
const tempQuestions = this.state.questions
    const result = tempQuestions.filter(function(value, index1) {
      return index !== index1
    })
    this.setState({
      questions: result
    })
```

How to avoid such case?

Comment: What duplication exactly are you worried about here…?

Comment: @deceze temp variable can be reduced using spread right?

Comment: So you want to remove duplicates from this.state.questions?

Comment: What "temp variable" exactly? `tempQuestions`? I don't know why you use that at all. Why not `const result = this.state.questions.filter(...)`?

Comment: You can also use the `Array#splice` function instead of the `.filter` method. No need for iteration here.

Comment: What is `index`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks pretty straightforward:

```
this.setState({
  questions: this.state.questions.filter((q, i) => index !== i)
})
```

Using `splice` will require cloning the array first, otherwise `setState` won't notify a state change. So an iteration is required either way, for that `filter` makes more sense than `splice`.

Comment: agree, coz declaring temp variable everywhere make it hard to read

Comment: one question, since `q` is not required, can we remove it? or we must have for the sake of bringing the `i`?

Comment: @Melissa94 `filter`'s callback expects the first parameter to be the value. We can't just omit it. I've seen people using `_` as that parameter name to show that it's should be there but it is useless: `.filter((_, i) =>`. That doesn't mean that it was omitted, it just means we don't use it. `_` is a valid variable name BTW.

Comment: in my code editor, there's this linter installed, so q will always be `unused`, that's why I think how can I get rid of it.

Comment: @Melissa94 I've never used a linter before, but I guess you can disable it for that particular line, right?

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Since you know which index value you want to remove. As @undefined mentioned you can use `Array.prototype.splice()` method to remove the value rather than iterating the entire array

Check below solution which will remove one index value

```
const { questions } = this.state;
const result = questions.slice();
result.splice(index, 1);
this.setState({
  questions: result
})
```

Comment: It seems she just want to remove an element by it's index. I'd suggest the old  `Array#splice` method.

Comment: Nothing. There is no need to iterate in this case. Using `Array#splice` makes more sense here. `.splice` modifies the original array though. For avoiding this, you can clone the array beforehand by using the `.slice` method: `let result = arr.slice(0).splice(index1, 1)`

Comment: @undefined Thanks for correcting me. I agree with that. splice makes more sense than iterating entire array to remove index value.

Comment: @undefined notice `index !== index1`. Your `splice` does the opposite. At least in the way you're using it.

Comment: @Think-Twice when to use filter since splice is the answer?

Comment: @Melissa94 This is the opposite of what you want. Instead of removing the element at `index`, it just removes every other element and keeps that element.

Comment: @Melissa94 In case you know the index using splice would be an O(1) operation while using filter is an O(n) operation. This explains well

Comment: but it have to have one temp variable

Comment: @Think-Twice Your solution does the opposite of what OP wants. When you fix that, you'll have another problem, to fix that problem you'll need to clone the array first. Thus making `splice` solution not a O(1) operation, but a O(n) one, which is the same as `filter` but more complicated.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir "does the opposite of what OP wants"? That's not true. What OP wants? Removing an element by index. [`splice` is an option](http://jsfiddle.net/yc064o83/).

Comment: @undefined And what does `splice` return? The array minus that element? Or a new array containing the removed elements?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value

Comment: @undefined [not my words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817491/refactor-es5-to-es6-to-avoid-declaring-temporary-variable/52817861#comment92552889_52817638): `let result = arr.slice(0).splice(index1, 1)`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir That's my comment, of course. What is wrong there?

Comment: @undefined https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice#Return_value

Comment: @Think-Twice I have updated your answer. I just noticed you are using the removed element(s) from the array as the result instead of the array without that specific element. It seems the code in my first comment had confused you, if this is the case, sorry about that.